# How can I make a list widget contain items from a folder and set a variable to the selected one Python PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm attempting to make a mini [Photoshop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Photoshop) application in [PyQt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt). I am not the best with PyQt, so I just took an old project and guessed with the Layouts so don’t expect something organized. Anyway, I want to make a QListWidget contain images from a folder called "unedited" and display them. Also when I select an image I want to save the path in a variable (relative path). How can I do that?

Code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import json
import os

app = QApplication([])

main_win = QWidget()
main_win.resize(1000, 500)
main_win.setWindowTitle('Scuffed Photoshop')

save_button = QPushButton("SAVE")
blur_button = QPushButton("Blur")
sharpen_button = QPushButton("sharpen")
bw_button = QPushButton("Black & White")

l = os.listdir("unedited")

list1 = QListWidget()

for i in l:
    list1.addItem(str(i))



images = QListWidget()

line1 = QVBoxLayout()
line2 = QVBoxLayout()
line3 = QHBoxLayout()

line2_line1 = QHBoxLayout()
line2_line2 = QHBoxLayout()

line3.addWidget(images, alignment = Qt.AlignLeft)


line2_line2.addWidget(save_button, alignment = Qt.AlignBottom)
line2_line2.addWidget(blur_button, alignment = Qt.AlignBottom)
line2_line2.addWidget(sharpen_button, alignment = Qt.AlignBottom)
line2_line2.addWidget(bw_button, alignment = Qt.AlignBottom)

linesV = [line1, line2]

line3.addLayout(line2)

for i in linesV:
    line3.addLayout(i)

line2.addLayout(line2_line1)
line2.addLayout(line2_line2)

main_win.setLayout(line3)

main_win.show()

app.exec_()
`
```

For the images, just use random photos. It doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 0):

It's way easier for the images listing view to use a QTreeView + QFileSystemModel.

```py
fs_model = QFileSystemModel()

uneditedp = Path(QDir.currentPath()).joinpath('unedited')
fs_model.setRootPath(str(uneditedp))

images_tree_view = QTreeView()
images_tree_view.setModel(fs_model)
images_tree_view.setRootIndex(fs_model.index(str(uneditedp)))

def image_double_clicked(index):
    image_path = fs_model.data(index, Qt.DisplayRole)
    print(image_path)


images_tree_view.doubleClicked.connect(image_double_clicked)

line1.addWidget(images_tree_view)
```

Comment: great but there is an error. Path isnt defined. Do i need to import something new?

Comment: Add *from pathlib import Path* at the top of the file (sorry about that)

Comment: great now it doesnt find the QDir. Sorry my imports are all over the place

Comment: these are my imports if it helps 
```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *# QIcon, QPixmap
from PyQt5 import *
from PIL import *
from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt
import json
from pathlib import Path
import os
```

Comment: from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir